# Number palindrome checker

Tags: c#, palindrome

My daughter, nine, recently had some homework looking at number palindromes. Part of the assignment was to take a number, reverse it, add the two together and repeat until she got a palindrome and to do this for several different numbers.

While helping her with this it struck me it'd be a nice simple idea for a computer program. She & I have messed about in Scratch a bit, but this sounded like a nice problem to do in a more commercial language. Thought I could write it and then show her how it worked.

So I did. It turned out to be not quite as child-friendly as I'd imagined.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;

namespace CheckNumberPalindrome
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string rollingSum;
            int iterations = 1;

            if(IsNumeric(args[0]) == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You did not enter a numeric value");
            }

            rollingSum = RecurseUntilPalindrome(args[0], ref iterations);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The final palindrome is {0}, which took {1} steps.", rollingSum, iterations));
        }

        private static bool IsNumeric(string s)
        {
            long result;
            return Int64.TryParse(s, out result);
        }

        private static string RecurseUntilPalindrome(string s, ref int iterations)
        {
            long rollingSum = AddToPalindrome(s);

            if(IsPalindrome(rollingSum.ToString()))
            {
                return rollingSum.ToString();
            }

            iterations++;
            return RecurseUntilPalindrome(rollingSum.ToString(), ref iterations);
        }

        private static long AddToPalindrome(string s)
        {
            string reversedString = ReverseString(s);
            long result = Convert.ToInt64(s) + Convert.ToInt64(reversedString);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Adding {0} to {1} = {2}", s, reversedString, result));
            return result;
        }

        private static string ReverseString(string s)
        {
            char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();
            Array.Reverse(charArray);
            return new string(charArray);
        }

        private static bool IsPalindrome(string s)
        {
            return s.SequenceEqual(ReverseString(s));
        }
    }
}
```

There are two questions here:

1. How could I make this better or cleaner or more efficient or any of the other things that CR does so well?
2. What could I do (beside hiding some of the functions in pre-compiled code elsewhere) to make this more child-friendly, or better for teaching/explaining some basic code concepts?

Comment: FWIW, `Console.WriteLine` has an overload that takes a format string and an array of objects so you don't need to use `string.Format`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overall your code looks very nice, readable and maintainable. I only have a few remarks:

- **Input validation:**

> ```
> if(IsNumeric(args[0]) == false)
>  {
>      Console.WriteLine("You did not enter a numeric value");
>  }
>  rollingSum = RecurseUntilPalindrome(args[0], ref iterations);
> ```

Why continue the program when the input is invalid (not numeric)? Check for a numeric value and only continue if the input is a number:

```
if(IsNumeric(args[0]))
{
    //Continue here...
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("You didn't enter a valid number!");
}
```

- ***Format* in `Console.WriteLine`:**

Following line:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The final palindrome is {0}, which took {1} steps.", rollingSum, iterations));
```

can be rewritten as:

```
Console.WriteLine("The final palindrome is {0}, which took {1} steps.", rollingSum, iterations);
```

No need to call the `String.Format`.

- **Check for palindrome:**

While writing previous points I found that there *had* to be an easier way to achieve the same result. There are numerous ways to check for a palindrome. For numbers you can also use this method:

```
public static bool IsPalindrome(Int64 input)
{
    Int64 reverse = 0;
    var temp = input;

    while (temp != 0)
    {
        var rem = temp % 10;
        reverse = reverse * 10 + rem;
        temp /= 10;
    }

    return reverse == input;
}
```

When using this method, there's no need for creating strings and arrays and again conversions to numbers. Your entire code can be written as follows:

```
Int64 startNumber;
var steps = 1;
var input = args[0];

if (Int64.TryParse(input, out startNumber))
{
    Int64 reversed;

    while(!IsPalindrome(startNumber, out reversed))
    {
        steps++;
        var temp = startNumber + reversed;
        Console.WriteLine("Adding {0} to {1} = {2}", reversed, startNumber, temp);
        startNumber = temp;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("The final palindrome is {0}, which took {1} steps.", startNumber, steps);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("You didn't enter a valid number!");
}
```

Comment: Nice, thanks. I went with comparing against a reverse string because I thought it would be easier to explain than how the maths works. Pretty silly of me to do recursion rather than a while loop, though - the latter is much easier to explain, too!

Comment: It's not illogical to use recursion but I try to avoid it when a simple loop can solve the problem. And I understand that 'reversing a string' is easier to explain to a 9-year old than the piece of math. Kudos for your daughter though for trying/willing to understand this matter! :)

Answer (score 3):

This may help with your second point about code concepts:

How about addressing the special case for when the user enters a palindrome?  It looks to me like you are assuming the entered number will not be a palindrome and you automatically add to it (calling RecurseUntilPalindrome).  How about adding an initial check to account for that case?  I think it would go along well with your numerical value input check (I consider invalid user input as a sort of special case as well).

To address your first point, I think your code looks pretty clean as is! Really easy to follow.

Comment: Thanks. A good thought - perhaps I'll take her through the code and then, if she's interested, help her put together the extra validation you're suggesting.